# Why isn't iphone SDK NSTimer calling the function I told it to?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer

I'm writing an application that has a timer functionality built in.  Unfortunately, I'm having problems with the NSTimer and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is where I'm declaring the timer...

```
if(!myTimer)
{
    NSLog(@"Setting up the timer!");
    myTimer=[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@selector(timerTicked)
                                  userInfo:nil 
                                   repeats:YES];
}
```

Thanks to the NSLog function, I know the code to set the timer up is going off, but it isn't calling the function:

```
-(void)timerTicked:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
//NSLOG that tells me that this function isn't being fired
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing a trailing colon on your selector name.  Should be something like this

```
selector:@selector(timerTicked:)
```

-- added after questioner comment

If it still doesn't work, check to make sure you are adding the timer to a run loop

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDECCEE

See the Discussion segment of the docs, it talks about how to add the timer to the run loop and points to the run loop docs, too.

Comment: OK, now that solves the problem.  I actually changed to 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval'; I had the wrong function.